# Failed to install Sedna ruby-gem 0.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sedna

I'm trying to install sedna xml database gem on ruby 1.9.2/rails 3.05. There is an errors list:
http://img101.imageshack.us/img101/2830/errorslist.png
Any ideas?

Comment: Please, use comments instead of answers ("add comment" beneath each question/answer). You can also edit your query to add additional information. And accept solution if it works ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite tricky thing on Windows as far as I know. Try this one solution: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.text.xml.sedna/2209 .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing the devkit. Have you installed/configured [devkit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit)?. 
If everything fails try this.

```
gem install sedna --platform=mswin32
```